# file-changes action raises an error with Github actions

Tags: github-actions

Hi I am using sqlfluff to lint and fix the pushed files, then using pre-commit to commit them in to the repo. i am also using  `trilom/file-changes-action@v1.2.4` to fetch the most recent changes in my PR. I had it working in to the branch I created these files, but after I merged them to the main it stopped fixing the files that I push in the new branches. Does anyone has similar experience with these actions?

here is my `sqlfluff_linter.yml` action:

```
name: lint
on:
  push:
jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      # Give the default GITHUB_TOKEN write permission to commit and push the
      # added or changed files to the repository.
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # requites to grab the history of the PR
          fetch-depth: 0
        continue-on-error: true
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        continue-on-error: true
      - id: file_changes
        uses: trilom/file-changes-action@v1.2.4
        with:
          output: 'space'
        continue-on-error: true
      - uses: pre-commit/action@v3.0.0
        with:
          extra_args: --color=always --files ${{ steps.file_changes.outputs.files}}
        continue-on-error: true
      - uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
```

I referred to this [comment](https://github.com/pre-commit/action/issues/7#issuecomment-669149713) while building this ^

and this my `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff
    rev: 1.3.2
    hooks:
      - id: sqlfluff-fix
        args:
          [
            --exclude-rules,
            'L051,L031,L030,L012,L046,L003,L011',
            '--dialect=clickhouse',
          ]
```

and this is the error I am getting :
[image]

am I getting rate limited here?

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/trilom/file-changes-action/issues/116. There are workarounds listed in there and the alternative actions too. You need to go through this thread.

Comment: Sure, no problem. What did you do to fix it? You might want to self-answer this how you fixed it to help others.